# mongodb failure to resync a stale member of a replica set

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have mongodb (version 4.2) replicaset with 3 nodes - primary, secondary, arbiter,
primary occupies close to 250 GB disk space, oplog size is 15 GB

secondary was down for few hours, tried recovering it by restarting, it went into recovering forever.

tried initial sync by deleting files on data path, took 15 hours, data path size went to 140GB and failed

tried to copy files from primary and seed it to recover secondary node
followed https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/
This did not work - (again stale)

in the latest doc (5.0) they mention to use a new member ID, does it apply for 4.2 as well?
changing the member ID throws error as IP and port is same for node I am trying to recover

This method was also unsuccessful, **planning to recover the node using different data path and port as primary might consider it as a new node, then once the secondary is up, will change the port to which I want and restart, will it work?**

please provide any other suggestions to recover a replica node with large data like 250 GB

Comment: Maybe try this one: [Sync by Copying Data Files from Another Member](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/#sync-by-copying-data-files-from-another-member). Note, use [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) to copy the data, run it several times. Run the first `rsync` while primary is running, it may take several hours. Then for the second run of `rsync`, shut down the primary, should be much faster.

Comment: Do you run any DDL (e.g. create index, drop collection, etc. ) while inital sync is running?

Comment: No, I do to run create index, drop collection while running initial sync, will evaluate rsync to copy files, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. shut down primary
2. Copying the data files from primary node, placing it in new db path (other than the recovering nodes db path)
3. changing log path
4. starting mongo service with different port (other than the one used by recovering node)
5. start primary
6. adding it to replicaset using rs.add("IP:new port") on primary

worked, could see the secondary node coming up successfully